# ¿Qué permisos debería tener un directorio para poder modificar sus archivos y directorios?

Tags: linux, apache

Necesito configurar los permisos de la carpeta de un tema de wordpress para poder subir, modificar y eliminar archivos y directorios desde un IDE que se conecta por SFTP a un servidor usando un usuario no root.

¿Qué comandos debería utilizar para poder configurar los permisos del directorio del tema y sus contenidos?

Answer (score 2):

En la situación ideal, el usuario de SFTP (por ejemplo `ubuntu`)  es el dueño de la carpeta del theme y todo su contenido.

El usuario además es miembro del mismo grupo que el usuario del webserver (por ejemplo `www-data`)

Esto se haría con

```
chown ubuntu:www-data wp-content/themes -R
```

Ahora, para los **archivos** contenidos en esa carpeta, necesitas que el usuario SFTP pueda crear, modificar, eliminar y leer esos archivos. En cambio, el webserver (apache, nginx, etc) sólo necesita leerlos.

Para los **subdirectorios** contenidos en esa carpeta, se repite lo mismo anterior (el dueño puede crear, leer, eliminar, el webserver sólo debe leer), pero **además**, tanto el usuario como el webserver necesitan permisos de ejecución sobre los subdirectorios, porque el permiso de ejecución sobre un subdirectorio es lo que te permite hacer

```
cd wp-content/themes/mi_theme
```

Sin permiso de ejecución, no hay `cd`, por ilógico que suene.

Entonces, te paras en la raíz de tu wordpress (algo asi como `/var/www/wordpress` supongo) y le das permiso 0640 (o 0644 si no estás seguro de que `ubuntu` y el webserver comparten el grupo `www-data`) a los archivos:

```
find ./wp-content/themes/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

y permiso 0750 (o 0755) a los directorios:

```
find ./wp-content/themes/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

**Nota** probablemente necesitarás que el directorio raíz de wordpress también tenga los mismos permisos.